# How to connect to MySQL, running on a Vagrant-based, Ubuntu 16.04 virtual server, remotely?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, heidisql

There probably isn't anything that I haven't tried, yet. So here goes...

I'm running a Vagrant-based virtual machine, with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The "ubuntu/xenial64" box, to be more precise.
MySQL (5.7.27 distribution) is correctly installed, external connections are allowed from any IP address (i.e. `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` already set within `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`). All privileges have been set for the DB user I'm using are correctly set, MySQL server is running and even accessible from within phpMyAdmin. Within `Vagrantfile`, the server has an IP address set and port forwarding is also set, for 3306 on both the host and on the guest:

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
```

What I'm trying to do is access MySQL from HeidiSQL, on the host. Below are the connection `Settings` and the `SSH tunnel` tabs:

[image]

[image]

Both the SSH username and password are "vagrant".

Once I try to open the conection, the first notification dialog I get is from PLink:

[image]

Then...

[image]

Everything should be fine! How am I sure? Because I've tried the **exact** same recipe on the "ubuntu/trusty64", i.e. the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box.

What can the source of this problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Remote `root` access is disabled by default in MySQL. Try running these commands to enable that:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

In your case user and password should both be dev.

I also had to run this command:
`sed -i "s/bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
followed by
`service mysql restart`

Also, I did not have to use an ssh tunnel.

You can then include them in the provisioning of your vagrant box, especially if you use shell provisioning.